# I need some help about ajax in wordpress always return 0

Tags: ajax, wordpress

This is the first time I try ajax in wordpress. I need some help.

in my theme's functions.php, I have:

```
function returnRandomPosts(){
    echo '123';
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_returnRandomPosts', 'returnRandomPosts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_returnRandomPosts', 'returnRandomPosts');
```

and in my single.php file, I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.post("<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>", {"action": "returnRandomPosts"}, function(response) {
            alert('response: ' + response);
    });
});
</script>
```

When I run the web page, it always alert "**response: 0**",

I hope you can give me some hints or tips, thank you.

update:

I checked the has_filter function, 
the new wp_ajax_XXXXX has successfully add into $wp-filters, 
BUT when I call AJAX into wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, has_filter function return false with wp_ajax_XXXXX

Anyone can give me some hint?

Comment: I've tried "Ajax on the Administration Side" in http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins,   it also return 0....

Comment: I just tried your exact code and it alerts **`response: 123`**...

Comment: I checked the has_filter function, 
the new wp_ajax_XXXXX has successfully add into $wp-filters, 
BUT when I call AJAX into wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, has_filter function return false with wp_ajax_XXXXX

Comment: Finally, I solved the problem.  I post the solution, thanks for brasofilo your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem.

I have a plugin, the function is, to preview another theme by adding "theme=name_of_theme" argument to url.

( For example, preview my homepage with "xxx.xx.xx/?theme=name_of_theme" )

The ajax failed in preview.

While I add the same ajax function code to the online page (ie. activated theme), it successes.

---

I hope my experience may help somebody.